# Redis Limit HKEYS

Tags: redis

can we limit hkeys result ??

```
HKEYS MyHash
```

result :

> 1) "oliver peoples"
>   2) "variant_mobile_tablets_accessori204136"
>   3) "ume flip cover for asus zenfone 5 lite a502cg pink"
>   4) "cle00048700057449"
>   5) "nev00048700007683"
>   6) "01xfh04870003242302"
>   7) "nev00048700001579"

and the problem :
i just want take only 5 row,
how to do it?

i've tried using 
- `SORT HKEYS MyHash LIMIT 0 10`
but still error.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the [SCAN command with the option COUNT](http://redis.io/commands/scan#the-count-option), looks like this is what you are looking for.

**UPDATE:**

As specified in the comments below you need to use the hash variant [HSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/HSCAN).

Comment: Good to specify @ItamarHaber

Answer (score 0):

@mauro-rocco

sorry for late response :

i've tried with HSCAN too, but the result its not as my expected.

```
HSCAN myHash 0
```

result :
1) "0"
2)  1) "oliver peoples"
   2) "{\"created_time\":\"2016-01-28 14:12:18\",\"modified_time\":null}"
    3) "variant_"
    4) "{\"created_time\":\"2016-01-28 15:12:16\",\"modified_time\":null}"
    5) "ume flip pink"
    6) "{\"created_time\":\"2016-01-28 15:12:35\",\"modified_time\":null}"
    7) "cle00048700057449"
    8) "{\"created_time\":\"2016-01-28 15:12:54\",\"modified_time\":null}"
    9) "nev00048700007683"
   10) "{\"created_time\":\"2016-01-28 15:13:11\",\"modified_time\":null}"
   11) "01xfh04870003242302"
   12) "{\"created_time\":\"2016-01-28 15:13:27\",\"modified_time\":null}"
   13) "nev00048700001579"
   14) "{\"created_time\":\"2016-01-28 15:13:43\",\"modified_time\":null}"
   15) "flash10"
   16) "{\"created_time\":\"2016-01-28 16:39:21\",\"modified_time\":null}"

and than i tried use count at the end

```
HSCAN myhash 0 match * count 1
```

but the result still more than one..

and the question still same : can we limit the result??
for ex : i just want get 5 row only, or 2 row only?